# How to refresh static resources in Java Web Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am developing an application that stores data dynamically and displays it as it is generated or uploaded. But the problem is when I am uploading any image then it should be displayed. It's path is also defined perfectly but until I refresh the whole application in eclipse it remains unchanged.
So to update application, I have to refresh it.

My application is Java based and is useing JSP and Servlet. Is there any code that can be used to update or refresh the application?

Right now I am doing it by right click -> refresh or directly F5 it.

Or suppose I want to create directory then where will I have to create it that will be accesses easily without refresh.

When I'll host my application then which place is better for to store data?
I know it's outside the web app but any specific place? Because there is no drive so how can I create or make directory and access that one in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any code that can be used to update or refresh the application?
>   Right now I am doing it by right click -> refresh or directly F5 it.

I think you need to look into the workspace re-fresh option in Eclipse ( was made available from Eclipse version 3.7.x ). You can enable it in *Preferences > General > Workspace* and select `Refresh on access` or as per need you can change to whatever setting you require.

[image]

> When I ll host my application then which place is better for to store data ? I know it's outside the web app but any specific place ? Because there is no drive so how can I create or make directory and access that one in my code.

The location of static content is best if placed outside of the scope of the project itself. Maybe some other directory on your server ( be it any directory ).

I can share what I have normally seen as a trend in different applications that I have personally worked on. We had a separate tomcat server that just hosted all static content ( all media ) and our web application accessed that static-server (as it was named) within a secured network. All hits to static content could only be made via our application server and thus all direct hits were either rejected or not entertained at all.

**Edit**

I would suggest using a an absolute path
and on windows environment
you will HAVE to use the drive lletter
and specify the path as X:\some\path
if you want to hide your letter drive
due to obvious security reason
I can suggest another idea

*Idea 1* : Make a separate drive (lets call it drive F) and make a folder with the name of "static". Then in your application , you just forward all requests to file uploads using this path ( F:\static......) . I would advise loading the directory name from a property file instead of hard-coding it in your code

*Idea 2* : If you cant make a separate drive, then make a directory namely "static" on the root of same drive ( C:\static ) . Make a user group and give him read/write permissions on this drive and revoke writing permissions from this user on all other drives ( just in case someone messes up with this user-group). Next do the same thing as above i.e specify this path into your application. One thing is that you would have to run your application with that specific user-group to ensure that the permissions security you have setup can be implemented.

Comment: How exactly are you placing your images in the project dynamically?  via any script ?

Comment: Using Upload mechanism, right now I am using `ServletContext sc=request.getSession().getServletContext();` `sc.getRealPath("product_images\\")`

Comment: From your application ? Wait, you mean that you are uploading these images via your application(that is running in your eclipse) and you want these images to be shown to you immediately as they are uploaded on the project path ? Correct me if I am wrong. Also this `product_images\\` is on the project root or it is on someother path ?

Comment: Yes I want to upload image in application and want to load immediately. And product_image\ is directory under which image stored. I want to store image outside the app but how can give it's path and if it isn't exist then how can I create that directory ?

Comment: For creating directories and paths , take a look into this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496700/how-to-use-printwriter-and-file-classes-in-java) . IMHO, it is the best solution for creating files in Java.

Comment: But sir i want to create directory without passing drive letter then is it possible, some kind of relative.

Comment: The path can be anything. Both relative and absolute. !

Comment: if i ll give "dir1/dir2/dir3" then where will it create this dirs ?

Comment: but where it will create this dirs ? inside app or outside ?

Comment: `dir1/dir2/dir3` these directories will be created from the point they are called ( in short within app ) .

Comment: Suppose I want to create it outside the app then what I ll have to do and without giving drive letter because when I ll host my app there is nothing like drive, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42949/discussion-between-saif-asif-and-java-curious-)

Answer (score 3):

A solution to this is a [design pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/) called [Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/interview-when-do-we-use-observer-and-observable). You should read about it.

Comment: No problem. If you are having problems understanding this, I can help you with a simple example.

Comment: Yes sir sure if it is possible.  I need it.

Comment: How observer pattern can help in this regard?

Comment: Whenever he wants to add/upload something.. he can notify observers and refresh the list/application

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to store such data outside the webapp's tree to avoid issues on redeployment.

You can't serve these files directly though, commonly it's done by creating a servlet mapped to eg. `images/*`; that parse the request URL (eg ) and based on that url fetches and serves. You need to set the correct MIME type for the output, and streamcopy the requested file to the servlet's output.

A well explained example of such a servlet can be found on [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Comment: I am using eclipse 4.3 (KEPLER).

Comment: it does have this preference as well

Comment: Yes I have checked it and that option is checked. But I want to reload or refresh whole application but it's not working till I manually refresh it. Is there any code or anything that help me ?

Comment: Sir I have read blog but still I don't understand what it mean ?? So If you will give me small example or idea about it then I ll be thankful to you.