# Java PrintWriter FileNotFound

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I'm having trouble with writing to a txt file. I am getting a FileNotFound Exception, but I don't know why because the file most definitely is there. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class Save
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Programs/Save Data Test/save.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.println("Hello World");
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesnt compile - PrintWriter throws that `FileNotFoundException` which needs to be handled

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496700/how-to-use-printwriter-and-file-classes-in-java

Comment: The code above wouldn't even compile. So there's no way you can get an exception.

Comment: Your title is literally just tags. Please update it to be a brief, meaningful description of your problem. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must create the actual file with its directory before you create the `PrintWriter` put

```
file.mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

Using this with the proper try and catch blocks would look something like this...

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class Save
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("save.txt");
        try {
            file.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println("Hello World");
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The asker said that "the file most definitely is there", which means that this won't solve it.

Comment: False. According to the Java documentation, the File parameter is "The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered." [Java 8 PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Answer (score 2):

Just because you know the file is there, doesn't mean your code should not check for its existence before attempting to process.

As far as your FileNotFound Exception, some if not all Java IDEs force you to write try/catch blocks if the IDE detects that an exception can occur.

NetBeans for example, The code won't even compile:

[image]

You have to code a try/catch block to handle a potential exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Programs/Save Data Test/save.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            pw.println("Hello World");
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            System.out.println(fnfe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to close() after println();

Answer (score 0):

turn this:  `public static void main(String[] args)`

into this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

and it will work just fine.