# no such file or directory when reading a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I know this a really simple question, but I am doing something wrong and it's driving me crazy!  I have a file named `input.csv` that I want to convert to a tab delimited file.

This is what I have, but it is saying `no such file or directory`.  The file is saved on my desktop, am I just missing something very simple?  any tips would help!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.csv"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a path issue pure and simple. You're not using the correct ***relative*** path to the file. .... Or if it's in a jar file, then you need to obtain it as a resource, not as a file.

Comment: Test the path to the user's directory, put in `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`, and then use this information to figure out what the relative path should be based on.

Comment: I had answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941269/where-the-file-will-be-located-while-using-io-streams-in-java-in-eclipse-ide/34941501#34941501).

It should solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Input the full path to your file (C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\thefile.csv). It's not throwing a permissions error so you just need to tell it where it is.

Comment: no, don't use the full path, use the relative path if at all possible.

Comment: Otherwise you're guaranteeing that the code will fail on all but one computer -- not good.

Comment: Sure, in this particular case though I assumed it was a one off utility. If it's a user-facing system most likely you would take some sort of input as to where the file is.

Comment: See my comment -- he needs to find his user directory and then base the relative path on this.

Comment: In that particular case I'm not sure how much good your answer is vs mine, he's talking about a CSV file so I can't imagine it's particularly likely to be something that multiple users have in the same relative location. But yes, that would be best practice for something that not only yourself is using.