# i want to display these two values in a text file

Tags: java

I have two string variables containing some user input.

```
        String name="neil";
        String mobile="5555";
```

now I want to display neil an 5555 in a text file. Please help me to display this in a text file, I know how to display content of a file which is already exist, but donot know how to work with this case, please help me...

Comment: Create a file and write to it ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I want. Actually want to write these 2 values to a file

Comment: First what you do in current servlet is bad. You declare the response to be a text/html one, but only send plain text. It is not bad to send plain text but you should set ContentType accordingly. Next if your question is *how to write two values to a text file* please ask **that** question and remove everything unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

This should be changed to use "java.io.File" class.
Has been explained in this thread: [How to use PrintWriter and File classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496700/how-to-use-printwriter-and-file-classes-in-java)

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/directory/file.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Something like this.

ps: check out "try-with-resources"